# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, state, undefined

What's the best way to solve this error? I gather it's because the `definition` is undefined at the time of render but why isn't the code rendering an empty string in that case?

It renders `<div>Not found</div>;` for a split second before it's a black screen and then I see that error in the console.

Based on the `console.log(dictionarySearch);` I can see it's being rendered 4 times per state change, which it shouldn't.

Dictionary:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect, } from "react";
const APIKEY = '';


const DictionaryDefinition = ({ dictionarySearch }) => {
    console.log(dictionarySearch);

    const [definition, setDefinition] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);


    useEffect(() => {

        const getDef = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            const res = await axios.get(`https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/${dictionarySearch}?key=${APIKEY}`)
            if (res) {
                setDefinition(res.data[0]);
                console.log(res.data);
                console.log(definition);
            }

            setIsLoading(false);

        }
        getDef().catch(console.error);
    }, [dictionarySearch]);

    if (!dictionarySearch) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    };

    if (definition.length === 0) {
        return <div>Not found</div>;
    };



    return (
        <>

           
                <div className="text-left">
                    <p className="text-4xl font-nitti">{definition?.meta.id || ""}</p>
                    <p className="text-lg font-nitti">{definition?.fl || ""}</p>
                    <p className="text-2xl font-guyot italic">{definition?.hwi.prs[0].mw || ""}</p>
                    <p className="text-4xl font-spaceGrotesk">{definition?.shortdef[0] || ""}</p>
                </div>
            
        </>
    )
}

export default DictionaryDefinition;
```

Comment: Can you check if `res.data[0]` has data in `setDefinition(res.data[0]);`

Comment: You could try `if (!definition || definition.length === 0)`

Comment: @RohitKhanna this helped thanks, I realised the shape of the response is different if it's a word that it's found, rather that returning empty it returns suggested words instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, import also React

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
```

Second, object's properties may also be undefined, so we can fix like this

```
...
  return (
    <>
      <div className="text-left">
        <p className="text-4xl font-nitti">{definition?.meta?.id || ""}</p>
        <p className="text-lg font-nitti">{definition?.fl || ""}</p>
        <p className="text-2xl font-guyot italic">
          {definition?.hwi?.prs?.[0]?.mw || ""}
        </p>
        <p className="text-4xl font-spaceGrotesk">
          {definition?.shortdef?.[0] || ""}
          {ar?.a1?.[0]}
        </p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
...
```

Comment: ``definition?.shortdef?.[0]`` ho do I check whether the [0] is null using this method?

Comment: You should control how the object is returned, if the `shortdef` has no elements, just keep it `undefined`. `definition?.shortdef?.[0]?.attr` also `undefined` if the element is `undefined` but only if `attr` is what you expect from element. If array element just a value not a object, you can check `definition?.shortdef?.[0] === undefined`. Anyhow, you can refer to this post [link](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-check-if-array-contains-undefined)